# Querying an Access table using the value selected in a combo

Tags: vb.net

I have started to build the application where I can navigate through a table in Access and bring in three text boxes the ProjectID, ProjectName and ProjectManager. I have also added 4 buttons (MoveNext, MoveBack, MoveFirstRecord and MoveLastRecord) that work.

At the moment, when I load the application I am able to navigate through the records and display in the text boxes the Project Name, Project ID and Project Manager. I can also move next, move back, move to the first record and move the last one without problems.

I have also managed to add a combo that displays all the Projects ID, which are always unique.

What I need to do is, by choosing a Project ID from that combo box and then clicking on a new button called "Search Project", to fill the text boxes with the appropriate information for the Project ID chosen in the combo.

I am quite lost and I don't know how to approach this in a efficient way.

This is the code I currently have:

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Dim DataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql1 As String
    Dim sql2 As String
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            connection.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\Corporate Reporting\2014_15\Corporate\QuarterlyReporting.accdb"
            connection.Open()

            '--For the text boxes--
            sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Projects_Application"
            DataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, connection)
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "Projects")

            '--For the combo--
            sql2 = "SELECT ProjectID FROM Projects_Application ORDER BY ProjectID"
            Dim cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql2, connection)
            Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                cmbSearch.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString)
            End While

            dr.Close()
            connection.Close()

            MaxRows = DataSet.Tables("Projects").Rows.Count
            inc = -1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub NavigateRecords()
        txtProjectName.Text = DataSet.Tables("Projects").Rows(inc).Item(0)
        txtProjectID.Text = DataSet.Tables("Projects").Rows(inc).Item(1)
        txtProjectManager.Text = DataSet.Tables("Projects").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If inc <> (MaxRows - 1) Then
            inc = inc + 1
            NavigateRecords()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        If inc > 0 Then
            inc = inc - 1
            NavigateRecords()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFirst_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
        If inc > 0 Then
            inc = 0
            NavigateRecords()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bntLastR_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntLastR.Click
        If inc <> (MaxRows - 1) Then
            inc = MaxRows - 1
            NavigateRecords()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        ??? ???
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: do you need `sql2 = "SELECT distinct ProjectID ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your search click event;

```
sql2 = "SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Projects_Application where ProjectID = '" & cmbSearch.value & "'"
Dim cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql2, connection)
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read
  textbox1.text = dr(0)
  textbox2.text = dr(1)
  textbox3.text = dr(2)
End While
dr.Close()
connection.Close()
```

Note: col1,2,3 ect would be the columns in your database, and textbox1,2,3 would be the textboxes you wish to have data displayed.  Read only.

Comment: Hi Wiliey, that really worked. I had to do some minor tweaks but it basically run well. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Would you mark it as answered please?

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is already local (in memory), you don't need to query the database for it, you can run queries against the table.  This link explains it pretty well: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx)

Here is an example from that site:

```
Dim table As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("Orders")

' Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date. 
Dim expression As String
expression = "Date > #1/1/00#" 
Dim foundRows() As DataRow

' Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
foundRows = table.Select(expression)
```

Comment: Hi Beth! You are right, I should look into the DataTable.Select Method because it looks quite useful. However, I never know how to fit new things in the code or how to combine with the code I already have. I will have to so further research. Thanks anyway :)